# How to limit decimal digit of GeoJSON

Tags: postgis, geojson

I am using postGIS. I am using ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) function to get GeoJSON data of Geom field. Its returning a long lat value that have 13 digits after decimal point. Is there any way to reduce or limit the decimal digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the [documentation of the method](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html). You can pass a parameter to limit the number of decimal digits.

```
text ST_AsGeoJSON(geography geog, integer maxdecimaldigits=15, integer options=0);
```